# Is there any extension to generate one RMA ID for multiple orders in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rma

Is there any paid extension to generate one rma for multiple orders ? If you anybody have an idea about it please suggest me or is this possible way to generate one RMA for multiple orders even there might be different shipping address.